# Dynamic Textbox from Data Values

Tags: kibana, vega-lite, vega

I need your help again. Now I need to build a textbox with dynamic text in it. It should look like this:

[image]

The code of the shown box is this:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v5.json",
  "autosize": "none"
  "width": 170
  "height":80,
  "padding": 10,

  "data": {
    "name": "daten",
    "values": [
      {"c1": "1", "c2": "2", "text": "TextboxText01"},
      {"c1": "1", "c2": "2", "text": "TextboxText01"},
    ]
  },

  "marks":[  
    {"type": "text",
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "x": {"value": 80},
          "y": {"value": 20},
          "dx": {"value": 0},
          "text": {"value": "Textbox-Line01"},
          "align": {"value": "center"},
          "fontSize": {"value": 14},
        }
      }
    },
    {"type": "text",
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "x": {"value": 80},
          "y": {"value": 60},
          "dx": {"value": 0},
          "text": {"value": "Textbox-Line02"},
          "align": {"value": "center"},
          "fontSize": {"value": 14},
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I display the text column from the data in the textbox?

Thanks in advance Joerg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your example, change the lines in marks to

```
"text": {"signal": "data('daten')[0]['text']"},
```

and

```
"text": {"signal": "data('daten')[1]['text']"},
```

[View in Vega on-line editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykSArJQBWENgDsQAGhBIGmNhBoAvOGhDiJamQHcaAE3poAjAHYADDPg0yWNAA5LIHEn36a4siaf6kmFKgA2qDiSAhq6L6YcJIyxEgANgxwEGjBIFDG6lkyUABM6gUy0QAemOoAKnBlTGwlVWXmWQC+UqCZ2dIZBehFIKXl6A2YtfXVmOYFzQC6MzLIAE4A1qlBoJgAnjgR-eNdMVBs+hGgMdELaKAllyDxSRGOrSAbN3fJaHnmT-rXqKBvES+xT2fxASjIoQS6iiSAAFAByKIxeEASkC5mmgXhA3h0xAT0SNkkoIB6igZzgFyeADMJJgAMoqE63RLvVDGAAszW5rXWWx2A324kOxxuFIuoN+-1ZDyBz1eMrQADY5T8Ffc0HLBaDwZDoX44Yi-Mi0cZMdjxrj8TJCRD1WyMuLrSBaeIGUz7RFOTyZs0gA)

[image]